# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String' in Scaffold-DbContext .Net Core

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first, package-manager-console

I use the following method to use Databases:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=[serverName] ; Database=[DatabaseName]; user id= [UserId] ; password = [Password];" 
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
        -Project "[ProjectName]" -Force 
        -ContextDir "[DirectoryNameOutPut]\Context" 
        -OutputDir "[DirectoryNameOutPut]" 
        -UseDatabaseNames -NoPluralize
```

But in some databases, I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

This error occurs after the `Scaffold-DbContext` command is written in the Package Manager Console and I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and does not classify any of the tables.

What can I do to fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-Verbose` flag to your `Scaffold-DbContext` to get more details.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=[serverName] ; Database=[DatabaseName]; user id= [UserId] ; password = [Password];" 
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
        -Project "[ProjectName]" -Force 
        -ContextDir "[DirectoryNameOutPut]\Context" 
        -OutputDir "[DirectoryNameOutPut]" 
        -UseDatabaseNames -NoPluralize
        -Verbose
```

Comment: Gives a series of information and it is unclear how to find the error from this information? @MrMoeinM

Comment: @MohammadHasanSalmanian Could you please update your question and share this info.